$H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$-regularity of tangent vector field defined on smooth boundary
Suppose that $\Omega$ is a bounded, smooth, simply connected domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $p(x):\partial \Omega \to \mathbb{S}^2$ be a vector field such that it lies on the tangent plane of $x \in \partial \Omega$. We have so many choices of such a vector field $p(x)$, does there exist such a $p(x)$ so that it is in $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$ for general bounded, smooth, simply connected domain? What is the optimal regularity we have?
As the boundary of the domain is smooth, we can suppose that $\partial\Omega=\mathbb{S}^2$. I am going to compute the $H^{1/2}(\mathbb{S}^2)$ norm of the example $p(x)=\left(\dfrac{-x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}},\dfrac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}},0\right)$. It is enough to compute the seminorm:
$$[p]_{H^{1/2}(\mathbb{S}^2)}=\int_{\mathbb{S}^2}\int_{\mathbb{S}^2}\dfrac{|p(x)-p(y)|^2}{|x-y|^3}dS^2_xdS^2_y.$$
We can use the spherical coordinate:
$$[p]_{H^{1/2}(\mathbb{S}^2)}=\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{2\pi}_0\int^\pi_0\int^\pi_0\frac{2 \left(1 - \sin(\varphi) \sin(\varphi^*) - \cos(\varphi) \cos(\varphi^*)\right) \sin(\theta^*) \sin(\theta)}{\left(\left(\sin(\theta) \cos(\varphi) - \sin(\theta^*) \cos(\varphi^*)\right)^2 + \left(\sin(\theta) \sin(\varphi) - \sin(\theta^*) \sin(\varphi^*)\right)^2 + \left(\cos(\theta^*) - \cos(\theta)\right)^2\right)^{3/2}}d\theta d\theta^* d\varphi d\varphi^*.$$
It seems to me that the integral is complicated. The singularity is on the set $\{\theta=\theta^*=\varphi=\varphi^*\}$. Is there any good idea to compute this?

Your latest edit misinterpreted the HB theorem: You do not need any hard theorems to construct such a vector field and, moreover, there will be vector fields with different orders of vanishing at the poles. At this point, you do not have a well-formed question....

@MoisheKohan thanks for the comment. I have computed some example on $S^2$, like the normalisation of $(-y,x,0)$ and $(xz,yz,z^2-1)$, it seems to me that their normalisation are not $H^1(\Omega)$.

You should do computations in the plane not on the sphere, since it is a purely local issue. And, right, it is probably in a fractional Sobolev space, so you should do a computation with some singular integrals.

I am trying to compute the examples in $H^1(\Omega)$ so that we can use the trace theorem to determine if they are in $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$. Do you think I should compute the $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$ norm directly?

Yes, I think so.

Do you have any idea to compute the singular integral? I have transformed it into spherical coordinates, but still seem very complicated.

You should update your question to include your calculations. Why would you use spherical coordinates? It is a calculation in the plane, forget about the sphere.

I do not quite understand why it is on the plane, as I think $p(x)$ is from $\mathbb{S}^2$ to $\mathbb{S}^2$.
